# Alter table to apply partitioning by key in mysql

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a table with million of rows and the frequency of growth will probably increase in future, so far about 4.3 million rows are added in a  month, causing the database to slow down. I have already applied indexing but it's not really optimizing the speed. Is applying Partitioning to such data favorable? 
Also how can I apply partitioning on a table with million of rows? I know it will look something like this

```
ALTER TABLE gpsloggs
    PARTITION BY KEY(DeviceCode)
    PARTITIONS 10;
```

The problem is I was Partitioning on DeviceCode which is not a primary key so partitioning isn't permissible.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gpslogss`;
CREATE TABLE `gpslogss` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DeviceCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Latitude` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Longitude` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Speed` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `rowStamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Time` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AlarmCode` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY `Id` (`Id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `DeviceCode` (`DeviceCode`) USING BTREE
);
```

So I altered the table and made the table in a new database with 0 records this way and it worked fine

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gpslogss`;
CREATE TABLE `gpslogss` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DeviceCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Latitude` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Longitude` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Speed` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `rowStamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Time` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AlarmCode` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   KEY `Id` (`Id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `DeviceCode` (`DeviceCode`) USING BTREE
);

PARTITION BY KEY(DeviceCode)
PARTITIONS 10;
```

How should I render the code so that I can apply partitioning to the table with million of rows? How should I drop keys and alter the table to apply partitioning without damaging data?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  Don't.

Long answer:  `PARTITION BY KEY` does not provide any performance benefit (that I know of).  And why else use `PARTITION`?

Other notes:

You should use InnoDB for virtually all tables.

InnoDB tables *should* have an explicit `PRIMARY KEY`.

There is a `DATETIME` datatype; don't use `VARCHAR` for date or time, and don't split them.

`latitude` and `longitude` are numeric; don't use `VARCHAR`.  `FLOAT` is a likely candidate (precise enough to differentiate vehicles, but not people).

Your real question is about speed.  Let's see the slow `SELECTs` and work backward from them.  Adding `PARTITIONing` is rarely a solution to performance.